# Radio Button Group: get text of selected radio button

Tags: sapui5

I have `sap.m.RadioButton` group in my view:

```xml
<RadioButtonGroup select=".changeRegion">
  <RadioButton id="rb-S" text="S" />
  <RadioButton id="rb-MW" text="MW" />
  <RadioButton id="rb-NE" text="NE" />
  <RadioButton id="rb-W" text="W"/ >
</RadioButtonGroup>
```

In my controller:

```js
changeRegion: function(e) {
  console.log(e.getParameter("selectedIndex"));
},
```

I am able to access the index of the selected radio button. Is there any way to **get the text of the selected radio Button**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's definitely possible. You already have the index, now you just need the collection of radiobuttons and select the radionbutton with the corresponding index. Once you have that radiobutton, you can read it's text.

This is how it could be done:

```
var idx = e.getParameter("selectedIndex");
var button = e.getSource().getButtons()[idx];
var txt = button.getText();
```

Or in short:

```
var txt = e.getSource().getButtons()[e.getParameter("selectedIndex")].getText()
```

You can check out [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cosiwe/1/edit?html,output) to see it in action

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be:

```
e.getSource().getSelectedButton().getText();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a different option to read the selected radio button text.. Just if someone needs it.

You need to set an Id to your Radio Button group, e.g:

```
<m:RadioButtonGroup id='radioButtonGroup' valueState="" select="changeRegion()">
<m:buttons>
<m:RadioButton id="rb-S" text="S"/>
<m:RadioButton id="rb-MW" text="MW"/>
<m:RadioButton id="rb-NE" text="NE"/>
<m:RadioButton id="rb-W" text="W"/>
</m:buttons>
```

Then you can get the Text from the selected radio button like this:

```
var text = sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("radioButtonGroup")).getSelectedButton().getText();
```

Comment: Recently learned an alternative to `sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("radioButtonGroup"))` which is `this.getView().byId("radioButtonGroup")`. I've read that sap.ui.getCore() is not recommended